# Proof of a subgroup $G \subset 〈\mathbb{Z}; +〉$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm struggling with the following question:

Prove that if $G$ is a subgroup of $\langle Z; +\rangle$ then $G=\{n·d\mid n∈\mathbb{Z}\}$ for some $d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I feel this is too generic, I don't even know how to start :/
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: Hint; if $G\neq \{0\}$ then pick $d$ to be the smallest positive element of $G.$

Comment: Also use the fact that for every $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $a>0$ there exist unique $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=a\cdot q+r$ and $0\le a<r$.

Comment: In case you need it, Theorem 3.1 (Chapter I) on Hungerford's book.

Comment: Thanks! Picking d as smallest integer apparently does it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets make the comments into a proof. If $G\neq\{0\}$ then pick $d$ to be the smallest positive element of $G$.

To see that $G=\{n\cdot d\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, suppose there exists some $k\in G$ such that $k\neq n\cdot d$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. By the division algorithm, there exists some remainder $d>r>0$ such that $k=m\cdot d+r$. As $G$ is a subgroup, it follows that $r=k-m\cdot d\in G$. This is a contradiction, as $d$ is the smallest positive element of $G$ but $d>r>0$. Hence, there is no such $k\in G$, so $G$ has the required form.